# find and replace nth occurrence of a pattern in xml file using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have two vmdk files in a ova. ovf file which is an xml contains capabilities of both vmdk files.
File content is as below

```
<ovf:VirtualSystem ovf:id="VMDK1">

                    <ovf:Item>
                    <rasd:AllocationUnits>hertz * 10^6</rasd:AllocationUnits>
                    <rasd:Description>Number of Virtual CPUs</rasd:Description>
                    <rasd:ElementName>8 virtual CPU(s)</rasd:ElementName>
                    <rasd:InstanceID>6</rasd:InstanceID>
                    <rasd:Reservation>9000</rasd:Reservation>
                    <rasd:ResourceType>3</rasd:ResourceType>
                    <rasd:VirtualQuantity>8</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
                    <rasd:Weight>8000</rasd:Weight>
                    <vmw:CoresPerSocket ovf:required="false">8</vmw:CoresPerSocket>
                </ovf:Item>
                <ovf:Item>
                    <rasd:AllocationUnits>byte * 2^20</rasd:AllocationUnits>
                    <rasd:Description>Memory Size</rasd:Description>
                    <rasd:ElementName>12288 MB of memory</rasd:ElementName>
                    <rasd:InstanceID>7</rasd:InstanceID>
                    <rasd:Reservation>12288</rasd:Reservation>
                    <rasd:ResourceType>4</rasd:ResourceType>
                    <rasd:VirtualQuantity>12288</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
                    <rasd:Weight>122880</rasd:Weight>
                </ovf:Item>
</ovf:VirtualSystem>
```

```
<ovf:VirtualSystem ovf:id="VMDK2">

                    <ovf:Item>
                    <rasd:AllocationUnits>hertz * 10^6</rasd:AllocationUnits>
                    <rasd:Description>Number of Virtual CPUs</rasd:Description>
                    <rasd:ElementName>14 virtual CPU(s)</rasd:ElementName>
                    <rasd:InstanceID>7</rasd:InstanceID>
                    <rasd:Reservation>9000</rasd:Reservation>
                    <rasd:ResourceType>3</rasd:ResourceType>
                    <rasd:VirtualQuantity>14</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
                    <rasd:Weight>14000</rasd:Weight>
                    <vmw:CoresPerSocket ovf:required="false">14</vmw:CoresPerSocket>
                </ovf:Item>
                <ovf:Item>
                    <rasd:AllocationUnits>byte * 2^20</rasd:AllocationUnits>
                    <rasd:Description>Memory Size</rasd:Description>
                    <rasd:ElementName>15360 MB of memory</rasd:ElementName>
                    <rasd:InstanceID>8</rasd:InstanceID>
                    <rasd:Reservation>15360</rasd:Reservation>
                    <rasd:ResourceType>4</rasd:ResourceType>
                    <rasd:VirtualQuantity>15360</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
                    <rasd:Weight>153600</rasd:Weight>
                </ovf:Item>

</ovf:VirtualSystem>
```

Using sed i would like to change below CPU configurations of only VMDK2.

```
<rasd:ElementName>14 virtual CPU(s)</rasd:ElementName>
<rasd:VirtualQuantity>14</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
<vmw:CoresPerSocket ovf:required="false">14</vmw:CoresPerSocket>
```

Please note that i do not want to modify either memory configuration of VMDK2, which also has VirtualQuantity element.

I tried below but it is modifying both VMDK1 and VMDK2 CPU configurations.

```
sed -i "/hertz/,/CoresPerSocket/s/[0-9]\+ virtual CPU/$cores virtual CPU/
/hertz/,/CoresPerSocket/s%<rasd:VirtualQuantity>[0-9]\+</rasd:VirtualQuantity>%<rasd:VirtualQuantity>$cores</rasd:VirtualQuantity>%
/CoresPerSocket/s/[0-9]\+/${cores}/" $ovf
```

Comment: Have you considered a parser instead?

Comment: If this is a true XML file please provide the `xmlns` name space declarations from the beginning of the file and the top-level enclosing element. (You can't have two elements at the top level in an XML file.)

Comment: Of course it is modifying both, because you didn't restrict it to VMDK2. If the CPU section is always the first item, you can start your area from `/id="VMDK2"/` instead of `/hertz/`, but note that using a real XML parser like roaima suggests is always the safer solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it properly, with an XML parser that understands XML.

```
ncpus=16
xmlstarlet edit \
    -N xmlns:ovf="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" \
    -N xmlns:vcloud="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5" \
    -N xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData" \
    -N xmlns:vmw="http://www.vmware.com/schema/ovf" \
    --var vi '//ovf:VirtualSystem[@ovf:id="VMDK2"]/ovf:Item[rasd:Description="Number of Virtual CPUs"]' \
    --update '$vi/rasd:ElementName' --value "$ncpus virtual CPU(s)" \
    --update '$vi/rasd:VirtualQuantity' --value "$ncpus" \
    --update '$vi/vmw:CoresPerSocket' --value "$ncpus" \
    ova.ovf
```

This picks out the block for `<ovf:VirtualSystem id="VMDK2"/>` and then the subsection `<ovf:Item/>` that contains `<rasd:Description>Number of Virtual CPUs</>`. It then replaces the CPU count with the value of the shell variable `$ncpus` (16 in my example). The `-N {namespace}` parameters are required so that `xmlstarlet` can parse the XML data correctly. (With a simple single namespace we can often use the default `_` name, but here we need to identify explicitly the namespaces for the various elements.)

I had to modify your original example to include sufficient XML to make it a legal XML file:

```
<Item xmlns:ovf="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1"
   xmlns:vcloud="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5"
   xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData"
   xmlns:vmw="http://www.vmware.com/schema/ovf"
>
<ovf:VirtualSystem ovf:id="VMDK1">

…your examples here…

</ovf:VirtualSystem>
</Item>
```

In common with many tools this command produces its edited output to *stdout*. You can use the *in place* flag if you really want to - but certainly not when testing - but my usual preference is to save the file as a backup and write the edited result to the original name. This approach works reliably for any tool, keeping hard links, permissions and other metadata that may have been present on the original unchanged:

```
xmlstarlet ... "original_file" >"original_file.$$.tmp" &&
    cp -fp "original_file" "backup_file" &&
    cat "original_file.$$.tmp" >"original_file"
rm -f "original_file.$$.tmp"
```

(If you don't care about hard links and metadata you can simplify this, replacing the `cat` with a `mv -f`.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shell variable `$cores` holds a value that has been assigned dynamically to it, i.e:  `cores=$(grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo)`,  then you can use something like:

```
awk -v RS='</ovf:VirtualSystem>' \
    -v ORS='</ovf:VirtualSystem>' \
    -v cores="$cores" \
    '/ovf:id="VMDK2"/ {
        sub(/<rasd:VirtualQuantity>[0-9]+<\/rasd:VirtualQuantity>/, "<rasd:VirtualQuantity>" cores "</rasd:VirtualQuantity>");
        sub(/<rasd:ElementName>[0-9]+ virtual CPU\(s\)<\/rasd:ElementName>/, "<rasd:ElementName>" cores " virtual CPU(s)</rasd:ElementName>");
    }
    NR > 1 { 
        print prev_rs 
    }
    {
        prev_rs = $0
    }
    END {
        printf("%s", prev_rs)
    }' your_xml_file.xml
```